# DefaultRedirect not working on mvc 4 web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, custom-errors, web-config

Hi there fellow programmers! I have a problem, I am facing a fancy problem of redirecting to a custom error page. Here is what i have in my web.config

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Message/DefaultError"    redirectMode="ResponseRedirect"  >
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/NotFound" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="/ServerError"/>
</customErrors>
</system.web>
```

on error 404 and 500 which were declared above were working fine, but my main problem is working with not enumerated errors such ass 400 etc.. i want to catch ALL OTHER ERROR on the default redirect action. or is that possible??? Help please????

Answer (score 1):

> i want to catch ALL OTHER ERROR on the default redirect action

Since 'All other errors' (400, 401 etc) will most likely be considered a **Server-Error** and not an **Application-Error**, you need to set the default page on the `<system.webServer>` section:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors defaultPath="/Message/DefaultError" defaultResponseMode="Redirect">
        <clear />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

See [Documentation](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but how about handling error 400 or bad request|??

Comment: Answer revised, I just noticed i missed some important parts. Anyway, it should handle 400 / Bad Request as well.

Comment: Yes, as it is affecting IIS configuration and it doesn't care whether your deployed application is in Debug mode.

Comment: i am trying it now. /Message/DefaultError is a controller/action for clarification

Comment: my web.config looks like this now:
       <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultPath="/Message/DefaultError" defaultResponseMode="Redirect">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/NotFound" responseMode="Redirect" />
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="500" path="/ServerError" responseMode="Redirect" />
    </httpErrors>

Comment: see that i put another "/" in the url

Comment: And what is the actual response?

Comment: error message saying its a bad request but not my custom page

Comment: still no luck even if i put the <error statusCode="400">